# Extract all text in body/p tag

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, extract, elementtree

My main task is to extract all text in `p` tag in `body` tag in the following XML file named "sample.xml":

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<newsItem >
<itemMeta>
<itemClass qcode="ninat:text"/>
<versionCreated>2018-01-16T12:05:19</versionCreated>
<pubStatus qcode="stat:usable"/>
<edNote role="sttnote:private">Aikamuoto printille</edNote>
</itemMeta>
<contentSet>
<inlineXML contenttype="xhtml/xml">
<html>
<body>
<p>Toiselle kierrokselle mennään, mikäli yksikään ehdokas ei ole saanut yli puolta ensimmäisellä kierroksella annetuista äänistä.</p>
<p>Vaaleissa ovat ehdokkaina <Person>Tuula Haatainen</Person> (sd.), <Person>Pekka Haavisto</Person> (vihr.), <Person>Laura Huhtasaari</Person> </p>
<p codej="obj:57654">Varsinaisena vaalipäivänä vaalihuoneistot ovat auki tuttuun tapaan kello 9:n ja 20:n välisenä aikana. Tällöin on äänestettävä siinä paikassa, joka kotiin jaettuun äänestyskorttiin on merkitty. Osa äänestäjistä sai kortin kotiinsa jo ennen joulua.</p></body>
</html>
</inlineXML>
</contentSet>
</newsItem>
```

Here is my code:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for teks in list(root):
    teksMain = teks.findall('p').text
    print('main body:', teksMain)
```

It did not work. My side task is to extract "obj:57654" from `<p codej="obj:57654">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the text of the `p` elements (including `Person` subelements and their `.tail`s), use [`itertext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.itertext).

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
 
tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
 
for p in tree.findall(".//p"):
    # Get all inner text 
    print("".join(t for t in p.itertext()))
 
    # Get the 'codej' attribute value (None if it does not exist)
    print(p.get("codej"))
```

Output:

```
Toiselle kierrokselle mennään, mikäli yksikään ehdokas ei ole saanut yli puolta ensimmäisellä kierroksella annetuista äänistä.
None
Vaaleissa ovat ehdokkaina Tuula Haatainen (sd.), Pekka Haavisto (vihr.), Laura Huhtasaari 
None
Varsinaisena vaalipäivänä vaalihuoneistot ovat auki tuttuun tapaan kello 9:n ja 20:n välisenä aikana. Tällöin on äänestettävä siinä paikassa, joka kotiin jaettuun äänestyskorttiin on merkitty. Osa äänestäjistä sai kortin kotiinsa jo ennen joulua.
obj:57654
```

Answer (score 0):

getroot() returns a single element, it's findall() that returns a list, so
you sould iterate over that instead. Also, I'm not sure why findall('p') doesn't find what
you want, but the xpath expression './/p' certainly does, try this:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for teksMain in root.findall('.//p'):
    print('main body:', teksMain.text)
```

Comment: Both answers worked, many thanks to @mzjn and joao, I found that these two solutions are work for a specific  XML file (in this case sample.xml), They did not work for other XML files.

Comment: No problem. But do have a look at [this
page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for details on the StackOverflow way
of doing things.

Comment: You are right" I'm not sure why findall('p') doesn't find what you want", A code works for this xml does not work for another XML of same type.