# Parsing the TextWithNodes element of a GATE document in Python

Tags: python, xml, nlp, elementtree, gate

On an NLP project, I need to process the text and annotations in the TextWithNodes element of a GATE XML document.  This element has the following appearance:

```
<TextWithNodes>
Some kind of sample <Node id="123" /> text 
in which <Node id="234" /> various Node 
elements appear.
</TextWithNodes>
```

The Node elements then correlate by ID attribute with annotations later in the same file.  This is apparently standard GATE syntax.  However, using the xml.etree.ElementTree module in Python, I cannot seem to capture the whole content of the TextWithNodes element.  If I enter this--

```
>>> tree = ET.parse('my_file.xml')
>>> twn = tree.find('TextWithNodes')
>>> twn.text
Some kind of sample
```

That is, I only get the first fragment of text before the first Node element.  How can I get the whole chunk of text, with the Node elements embedded in it?  Or is there a better way of goint about this?  I want, eventually, to turn the whole text content into a list of sentences, each element of which has the text of the sentence paired with a dictionary from Node ID to the text content of the corresponding annotation--something like that.  Thanks.

Comment: The missing text pieces are stored in the `tail` property of the `Node` elements. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/3683997/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/66182075/407651 (and many other questions).